# How to get number of views for a page using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I have a website and for each post that I write (that is a particular page) in my blog, I would like to show the number of views that Google Analytics tracks.

How to do this using Analytics API?

Or is it something related to Webmaster tools?

Thankyou

#### Please note...

I have a Google Analytics account correctly working and processing data.

Answer (score 3):

To get the visitor count per page using the Google Analytics API you would use the following API call.. Where ga?id= is the profile ID or

> "The namespaced profile ID of the profile from which to request data.
>   Use the profile selector above to find this value."

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%XXXXXX&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&metrics=ga%3Avisits&start-date=2012-09-01&end-date=2012-10-28&max-results=50
```

This returns the URL of the page on your website and the visitor count for the date range specified.

Answer (score -1):

This is easy to achieve.
You first connect to your GA account
You choose your website
Then, go to Content on the left menu and look at the bottom right position of the loaded page you will se all the pages accessed on your website.

Comment: Andry wants to use the API to get this information.

Comment: lol, oh yes, I see that :)